# Z3 FiniteDomain doesn't seem to work with implications

Tags: z3, sat

Here's a Z3 program, that creates two variables X and Y which cannot be equal, and have a domain of size 2:

```csharp
var solver = ctx.MkSolver();

// Section A
var T = ctx.MkFiniteDomainSort("T", 2);
var a = ctx.MkNumeral(0, T);
var b = ctx.MkNumeral(1, T);
var x = ctx.MkConst("x", T);
var y = ctx.MkConst("y", T);

// Section B
//var a = ctx.MkInt(0);
//var b = ctx.MkInt(1);
//var x = ctx.MkIntConst("x");
//var y = ctx.MkIntConst("y");
//solver.Add(ctx.MkLe(a, x), ctx.MkLe(x, b));
//solver.Add(ctx.MkLe(a, y), ctx.MkLe(y, b));

// Section C
//solver.Assert(!ctx.MkEq(x, y));

// Section D
solver.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(ctx.MkEq(x, a), ctx.MkEq(y, b)));
solver.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(ctx.MkEq(x, b), ctx.MkEq(y, a)));
solver.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(ctx.MkEq(y, a), ctx.MkEq(x, b)));
solver.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(ctx.MkEq(y, b), ctx.MkEq(x, a)));

// Section E
//solver.Assert(ctx.MkEq(x, a));

var status = solver.Check();
Console.WriteLine(status);
Console.WriteLine(solver.Model);
Console.WriteLine(solver.Model.Eval(ctx.MkEq(x, a)));
Console.WriteLine(solver.Model.Eval(ctx.MkEq(y, b)));

// Should always be true, but doesn't work when only sections A and D are uncommented?
Console.WriteLine(solver.Model.Eval(ctx.MkImplies(ctx.MkEq(x, a), ctx.MkEq(y, b))));
```

I get output.

```
SATISFIABLE
(define-fun y () T
  0)
(define-fun x () T
  0)
true
false
false
```

This model clearly does **not** satisfy the constraints. I explicitly evaluate the 1st constraint to double check, and indeed, it's false.

The same problem does not occur if I use integers (section B instead of section A), or I add additional constraints (section C & E).

What am I missing? I'd like to use FiniteDomain as it's more convenient than adding bounds to integers, but it seems it behaves quite differently.

Comment: This looks bizarre indeed. Please report it at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues and update this question with what you find out!

Comment: This could be explained if `ctx.MkNumeral` did actually not instantiate a value of sort `FiniteDomain` but, instead, of some other type. Some source code comments suggest using `Context.FromInt` to create a specific finite-domain value.

Comment: Patrick: That was my original thought as well, but in those cases, z3 usually throws a sort-error. (I replicated the same using the Python interface, and it also behaves weirdly just like the OP posted.) I wonder if there's some underlying assumption that finite-domains are only to be used with the fixed-point engine (i.e., horn-clauses), but if that's the case z3 should still spit out a reasonable error message. Curious.

Comment: @alias makes sense

Comment: I've filed https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/4842.

Answer (score 0):

[This GitHub issue](http://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/4842) explains that `FiniteDomain` is only intended for the Datalog engine, and is broken in other uses.

Using enumerations is the correct way to do this in Z3 in other engines.